# Can you use "gallows hill" as a general description for any execution site?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

When I try to google "gallows hill" I find only references to specific places named Gallows Hill. My question is, is it possible to use (lowercase) gallows hill as a description for an execution site in general, and say "the gallows hill" also about a place where for example beheadings took place? Or do you need to use "execution site" or "execution ground" (or something else) in that case?

Comment: Not every gallows was on a hill.

Comment: *gallows* very specifically means "a framework used for hanging".  Referring to a place where shootings or beheadings took place as a *gallows* anything will sound very strange.

Comment: No, you can't.  execution site, yes.

Comment: Thank you very much Lambie, stangdon and Michael Harvey!

Comment: @Lambie That looks like an answer to me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

I checked on Google ngram and while the usage you ask about is not exactly common, it does occur, especially in older texts. Here is an example, from [The Baltimore Literary and Religious Magazine, Vol. 7, 1841](https://books.google.com/books?id=PLceAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA323&dq=%22gallowshill%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjEs72vy434AhXsmmoFHbutCEk4FBC7BXoECAkQBg#v=onepage&q=%22gallowshill%22&f=false):

> My grandfather was a grown man at a period when the neighbouring proprietors could have dragged him from his cottage and hung him up on **the gallowshill** of the barony.

There are several other examples.

Looking across those, plus others where the initial letter “g” is capitalized, and where the word is either hyphenated or split in two, it seems clear that even when used generically, “gallowshill” is not synonymous with “execution site”. Rather, the former is a subset of the latter. That is, all gallowshills are execution sites, but not all execution sites are gallowshills.

Comment: gallowshill written as one word?

Comment: Yes, at least in the example I linked to. (It shows it hyphenated, but I can see from the ngram result that it is a single word.)

Comment: @tkp That is both interesting and useful, thank you, and also thank you for the tip about Google ngram!